# Using C FILE stream in C sockets programming

Tags: c, sockets, file, stream, abstraction

Am back with a question on using C File stream in sockets programming. I was reading about it and saw mixed reviews - some people say it's not reliable (ie leaky abstraction?).

Has any one got a view about using C File stream in sockets programming?

Comment: AFAIK, this should work only on certain compilers/operative systems, if any at all.

Comment: Thanks Simone! I should check if it works on my target platforms...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Don't.

The TCP and UDP protocols have too many semantics to be easily mapped to your usual file stream APIs. That's not to say it's impossible or even difficult, but there are likely to be lots and lots of gotchas and edge cases that will give you wildly unpredictable behaviour. I also cannot think off the top of my head of any applications where you might want to treat a socket as an ordinary file.

At the end of the day, once you've dealt with binding and listening and accepting, none of which you can do with C File streams, and wrapped the resultant file descripter in a File stream type, all you are going to do is use fread() and fwrite(), maybe fgetc(), so you may as well leave it as an ordinary file descriptor and use recv(), and send() and save yourself the hassle of wrapping. You may save yourself the hassle of dealing with buffering, but having control of the buffering allows you to tune your buffer to the application's requirements and save yourself some network overhead and speed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kind of application you're writing. `FILE` streams are not suitable for nonblocking, asynchronous, or `select`/`poll`-based IO. This may be no problem for a command line program that performs a sequential task of connecting to a server, making some request, and getting the results. It also works alright for a run-from-inetd-only server process. But if your application will be doing anything event-based, you're in trouble. If you really want to use `FILE` streams with sockets in an event-based application, you can make it possible using threads, but I doubt it's a good idea...

Comment: Thanks R..! My intention was to go for asynchronous connections. But I could scale it down to a sequential program for now. But I'm looking for something that can handle at least 80 concurrent connections. These connections will be sending non-stop data.